How to recover when refresh token expired with angular and auth0 sdk
I use auth0 with its angular sdk (version 2.2.3) and AngularJs 18. I noticed when debugging another problem with reduced refreshtoken lifetime that auth0 returns a 403 invalid_grant when the refresh token expired, but nothing happens. Only option to recover on my website is then to clean the localStorage.
AuthModule.forRoot({
            domain: environment.domain,
            clientId: environment.clientId,
            useRefreshTokens: true,
            cacheLocation: "localstorage",
            authorizationParams: {
                audience: environment.audience,
                redirect_uri: environment.redirect_uri
            }

How do I handle this and properly logout? I use token-rotation on auth0 if that matters.
I also would like to use an authGuard like this, however isAuthenticated is true, even when token are expired.
export const authGuard: CanActivateFn = (
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
) => {
  const auth = inject(AuthService);
  const router = inject(Router);

  return auth.isAuthenticated$.pipe(
    map((isAuthenticated) => isAuthenticated),
    tap((loggedIn) => {
      if (!loggedIn) {
        router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
    })
  );
};

There is a closed issue on github: https://github.com/auth0/auth0-angular/issues/596
It mentions:

There are a couple of things I can recommend:
Keep everything as is, but catch the mentioned error and redirect the
user to Auth0 to login again. Or you can set useRefreshTokensFallback
to true, which will fallback to iframes. Note that this relies on
third party cookies. So if these are blocked, or there is no active
session with Auth0, it will still throw login_required, which you need
to handle accordingly (e.g. by redirecting to Auth0 for logging in).

Is it as easy as subscribing to the error$in the app component onInit?
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.authService.error$.subscribe(error => {
      this.authService.logout();
    })

